# SQL SELECT Data from other table based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Gurus,
I have a table like below

```
Id Name Source Value
1   a      Dx   C
2   b      Rx   G
3   C      Tx   H
```

I have 3 other tables like T1,T2 and T3 with structure as below. Based on "Source" column in parent table, I need to fetch "Data column" and show as result. If multiple records match need all record as comma-seperated

```
T1

Id       Data
Dx        123
DX        011  
T2

Id       Data
Rx        456
Rx       022  

T3

Id       Data
Tx        789
```

I need Output as in T-SQL

```
Id Name Source Value Data
1   a      Dx   C     123,011
2   b      Rx   G     456 ,022
3   C      Tx   H     789
```

I tried with Case when but not successful. Need inputs

Comment: Either combination of coalesce and left joins, or case with sub-selects.

Comment: You'll need to provide some additional info. What decised what table should be hit? Is it the values of Source? It seems like it is, but would be good to know for sure.

Comment: Yes based on value of source the data should be populated

Comment: You mean T1 is always only DX values etc? Can it be more than one t1/t2/t3 row for an id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT, Name CHAR(1), Source CHAR(2), Value CHAR(1))
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(ID CHAR(2), Data NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(ID CHAR(2), Data NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @t3 TABLE(ID CHAR(2), Data NVARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, 'a', 'Dx', 'C'),
(2, 'b', 'Rx', 'G'),
(3, 'c', 'Tx', 'H')

INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Dx', '1231')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Dx', '1232')
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES('Dx', '1233')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('Rx', '4561')
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES('Rx', '4562')
INSERT INTO @t3 VALUES('Tx', '789')


SELECT  t.ID ,
        t.Name ,
        t.Source ,
        t.Value ,
        COALESCE(c1.Data1, c2.Data2, c3.Data3) AS Data
FROM @t t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Data 
             FROM @t1 t1 WHERE t.Source = t1.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') AS Data1) c1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Data 
             FROM @t2 t2 WHERE t.Source = t2.ID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') AS Data2) c2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + Data 
            FROM @t3 t3 WHERE t.Source = t3.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'') AS Data3) c3
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Source  Value   Data
1   a       Dx      C       1231,1232,1233
2   b       Rx      G       4561,4562
3   c       Tx      H       789
```

Version with `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT  t.ID ,
        t.Name ,
        t.Source ,
        t.Value ,
        o.Data
FROM    @t t
        OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    CASE t.Source
                                  WHEN 'Dx' THEN STUFF((SELECT
                                                              ',' + Data
                                                        FROM  @t1 t1
                                                        WHERE t.Source = t1.ID
                                       FOR             XML PATH('') ,
                                                           TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
                                  WHEN 'Rx' THEN STUFF((SELECT
                                                              ',' + Data
                                                        FROM  @t2 t2
                                                        WHERE t.Source = t2.ID
                                       FOR             XML PATH('') ,
                                                           TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
                                  WHEN 'Tx' THEN STUFF((SELECT
                                                              ',' + Data
                                                        FROM  @t3 t3
                                                        WHERE t.Source = t3.ID
                                       FOR             XML PATH('') ,
                                                           TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
                                END AS DATA
                    ) o
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. One small request is , Based on value only I can decide on table...I mean if "dx" then t1, if "rx" then T2 etc.. can you help me with modified query

Comment: @Saravanan, have a look at case version. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to `case`, use nested `ISNULL`s or `COALESCE` and `left outer joins`:

```
Select tbl.Id, tbl.Name, tbl.Source, tbl.value,
   isnull(isnull(T1.data,T2.data),T3.data) as data
from table tbl
left outer join T1 on tbl.Source = T1.Id
left outer join T2 on tbl.Source = T2.Id
left outer join T3 on tbl.Source = T3.Id
```